# How to initialize nested array of structs in GO?

Tags: go

I'm having this struct:

```
type RemedyCircuitsResp struct {
    Circuits []struct {
        RemedyCircuitID            string `json:"RemedyCircuitId"`
        Status                     string `json:"Status"`
        VendorName                 string `json:"VendorName"`
        VendorCommunityID          int    `json:"VendorCommunityId"`
        CommunityID                int    `json:"CommunityId"`
        ZLocCommunityID            int    `json:"ZLocCommunityId"`
        CircuitType                string `json:"CircuitType"`
        InstalledSpeed             string `json:"InstalledSpeed"`
        CircuitID                  string `json:"CircuitId"`
        CircuitSpeed               string `json:"CircuitSpeed"`
        CircuitFunction            string `json:"CircuitFunction"`
        ContractID                 string `json:"ContractId"`
        ALocName                   string `json:"ALocName"`
        ZLocName                   string `json:"ZLocName"`
        ExpectedMonthlyCircuitCost string `json:"ExpectedMonthlyCircuitCost"`
        ExpectedOneTimeCircuitCost string `json:"ExpectedOneTimeCircuitCost"`
        TotalCost                  string `json:"TotalCost"`
        CustomerMakeReadyComplete  string `json:"CustomerMakeReadyComplete"`
        CarrierOriginalDueDate     string `json:"CarrierOriginalDueDate"`
        CarrierCurrentDueDate      string `json:"CarrierCurrentDueDate"`
        CarrierCompletion          string `json:"CarrierCompletion"`
        EnaTurnUpDate              string `json:"EnaTurnUpDate"`
        SiteVisit                  string `json:"SiteVisit"`
        DisconnectRequested        string `json:"DisconnectRequested"`
        DisconnectEffective        string `json:"DisconnectEffective"`
    } `json:"Circuits"`
    ResponseStatus struct {
        ErrorCode  string `json:"ErrorCode"`
        Message    string `json:"Message"`
        StackTrace string `json:"StackTrace"`
        Errors     []struct {
            ErrorCode string `json:"ErrorCode"`
            FieldName string `json:"FieldName"`
            Message   string `json:"Message"`
        } `json:"Errors"`
    } `json:"ResponseStatus"`
}
```

I've tried to initialize Circuits and Errors but I don't know how:

```
    allCircuits := RemedyCircuitsResp{}
    allCircuits.Circuits = make([]RemedyCircuitsResp.Circuits, 0)
    allCircuits.ResponseStatus.Errors = make([]RemedyCircuitsResp.ResponseStatus.Errors, 0)
```

Visual Studio Code says:

```
RemedyCircuitsResp.Circuits undefined (type RemedyCircuitsResp has no method Circuits)
RemedyCircuitsResp.ResponseStatus undefined (type RemedyCircuitsResp has no method ResponseStatus)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot define an anonymous struct and then initialize it un-anonymously. If you want to do that, you have to type out the entire struct all over again. This way is easier.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Circuit struct {
    RemedyCircuitID            string `json:"RemedyCircuitId"`
    Status                     string `json:"Status"`
    VendorName                 string `json:"VendorName"`
    VendorCommunityID          int    `json:"VendorCommunityId"`
    CommunityID                int    `json:"CommunityId"`
    ZLocCommunityID            int    `json:"ZLocCommunityId"`
    CircuitType                string `json:"CircuitType"`
    InstalledSpeed             string `json:"InstalledSpeed"`
    CircuitID                  string `json:"CircuitId"`
    CircuitSpeed               string `json:"CircuitSpeed"`
    CircuitFunction            string `json:"CircuitFunction"`
    ContractID                 string `json:"ContractId"`
    ALocName                   string `json:"ALocName"`
    ZLocName                   string `json:"ZLocName"`
    ExpectedMonthlyCircuitCost string `json:"ExpectedMonthlyCircuitCost"`
    ExpectedOneTimeCircuitCost string `json:"ExpectedOneTimeCircuitCost"`
    TotalCost                  string `json:"TotalCost"`
    CustomerMakeReadyComplete  string `json:"CustomerMakeReadyComplete"`
    CarrierOriginalDueDate     string `json:"CarrierOriginalDueDate"`
    CarrierCurrentDueDate      string `json:"CarrierCurrentDueDate"`
    CarrierCompletion          string `json:"CarrierCompletion"`
    EnaTurnUpDate              string `json:"EnaTurnUpDate"`
    SiteVisit                  string `json:"SiteVisit"`
    DisconnectRequested        string `json:"DisconnectRequested"`
    DisconnectEffective        string `json:"DisconnectEffective"`
}

type Error struct {
    ErrorCode string `json:"ErrorCode"`
    FieldName string `json:"FieldName"`
    Message   string `json:"Message"`
}

type ResponseStatus struct {
    ErrorCode  string  `json:"ErrorCode"`
    Message    string  `json:"Message"`
    StackTrace string  `json:"StackTrace"`
    Errors     []Error `json:"Errors"`
}

type RemedyCircuitsResp struct {
    Circuits       []Circuit      `json:"Circuits"`
    ResponseStatus ResponseStatus `json:"ResponseStatus"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", RemedyCircuitsResp{
        Circuits: []Circuit{{}, {}, {}, {}},
    })
}
```

Alternatively you have to do something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type RemedyCircuitsResp struct {
    Circuits []struct {
        RemedyCircuitID            string `json:"RemedyCircuitId"`
        Status                     string `json:"Status"`
        VendorName                 string `json:"VendorName"`
        VendorCommunityID          int    `json:"VendorCommunityId"`
        CommunityID                int    `json:"CommunityId"`
        ZLocCommunityID            int    `json:"ZLocCommunityId"`
        CircuitType                string `json:"CircuitType"`
        InstalledSpeed             string `json:"InstalledSpeed"`
        CircuitID                  string `json:"CircuitId"`
        CircuitSpeed               string `json:"CircuitSpeed"`
        CircuitFunction            string `json:"CircuitFunction"`
        ContractID                 string `json:"ContractId"`
        ALocName                   string `json:"ALocName"`
        ZLocName                   string `json:"ZLocName"`
        ExpectedMonthlyCircuitCost string `json:"ExpectedMonthlyCircuitCost"`
        ExpectedOneTimeCircuitCost string `json:"ExpectedOneTimeCircuitCost"`
        TotalCost                  string `json:"TotalCost"`
        CustomerMakeReadyComplete  string `json:"CustomerMakeReadyComplete"`
        CarrierOriginalDueDate     string `json:"CarrierOriginalDueDate"`
        CarrierCurrentDueDate      string `json:"CarrierCurrentDueDate"`
        CarrierCompletion          string `json:"CarrierCompletion"`
        EnaTurnUpDate              string `json:"EnaTurnUpDate"`
        SiteVisit                  string `json:"SiteVisit"`
        DisconnectRequested        string `json:"DisconnectRequested"`
        DisconnectEffective        string `json:"DisconnectEffective"`
    } `json:"Circuits"`
    ResponseStatus struct {
        ErrorCode  string `json:"ErrorCode"`
        Message    string `json:"Message"`
        StackTrace string `json:"StackTrace"`
        Errors     []struct {
            ErrorCode string `json:"ErrorCode"`
            FieldName string `json:"FieldName"`
            Message   string `json:"Message"`
        } `json:"Errors"`
    } `json:"ResponseStatus"`
}

func main() {
    value := RemedyCircuitsResp{
        Circuits: []struct {
            RemedyCircuitID            string `json:"RemedyCircuitId"`
            Status                     string `json:"Status"`
            VendorName                 string `json:"VendorName"`
            VendorCommunityID          int    `json:"VendorCommunityId"`
            CommunityID                int    `json:"CommunityId"`
            ZLocCommunityID            int    `json:"ZLocCommunityId"`
            CircuitType                string `json:"CircuitType"`
            InstalledSpeed             string `json:"InstalledSpeed"`
            CircuitID                  string `json:"CircuitId"`
            CircuitSpeed               string `json:"CircuitSpeed"`
            CircuitFunction            string `json:"CircuitFunction"`
            ContractID                 string `json:"ContractId"`
            ALocName                   string `json:"ALocName"`
            ZLocName                   string `json:"ZLocName"`
            ExpectedMonthlyCircuitCost string `json:"ExpectedMonthlyCircuitCost"`
            ExpectedOneTimeCircuitCost string `json:"ExpectedOneTimeCircuitCost"`
            TotalCost                  string `json:"TotalCost"`
            CustomerMakeReadyComplete  string `json:"CustomerMakeReadyComplete"`
            CarrierOriginalDueDate     string `json:"CarrierOriginalDueDate"`
            CarrierCurrentDueDate      string `json:"CarrierCurrentDueDate"`
            CarrierCompletion          string `json:"CarrierCompletion"`
            EnaTurnUpDate              string `json:"EnaTurnUpDate"`
            SiteVisit                  string `json:"SiteVisit"`
            DisconnectRequested        string `json:"DisconnectRequested"`
            DisconnectEffective        string `json:"DisconnectEffective"`
        }{{}, {}, {}, {}},
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", value)
}
```